# Extract all highlighted text of a PDF into seperat Excel cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, adobe-reader

I create a lot of spreadsheets in Excel. Basically consisting of various columns. The problem is that one of these columns contains a lot of text (Whole paragraphs worth). The text inserted into this column is from a gigantic PDF file (this PDF file contains a lot of other stuff I don't need).

So far what I've done is to manually copy and paste the stuff I need from the PDF into excel

> Copy » Double click on cell » paste

This causes the text to lose formatting and when I paste the paragraph into a specific cell, I get lots of blank spaces that I need to manually remove.

> Click on cell » Backspace the empty blanks till the paragraph falls into a singular line at the formula bar » Wrap text for neatness

My solution to this is to

1. Copy multiple paragraphs into a MS Word table
2. Merge rows till each paragraph falls into a singular row
3. Fix formatting by removing paragraph breaks and replace them with spaces by the *find/replace* method followed by
4. Paste that into excel

Now these spreadsheets of mine can get rather large and this constant copy pasting is turning into a huge pain. Is there an easier way to go about this?

What I would ideally want is that each paragraph from the PDF should fall into a singular Excel cell, without the annoying blank spacing.

I was thinking of just highlighting the sections I need from the PDF and somehow extracting that from the PDF into an Excel column. Somehow magically inserting each paragraph into a different cell in a singular column without a ton of blank spaces.

*(Or)*

Inserting the whole PDF into excel (again somehow magically inserting each paragraph into a different cell in a singular column without a ton of blank spaces) and I can just delete the paragraph/stuff I do not need.

I know I'm not going to get the perfect solution, but any method that saves me time would be great!

This work I do is for school and there's no way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: It depends a lot on the nature of the PDF.  Contrary to what Adobe would have you believe, the PDF specification is a 900-page spaghetti mess with a lot of things that depend on both how the PDF was created and how it is read.

If the PDF in question has an embedded text layer in some useful format, such as `XML`, you could conceivably extract that layer only and use the `XML` to map the "paragraphs" to different Excel cells.  The specifics depend entirely on how the PDF file was created, what such a potential layer looks like, and your coding skills.

If you decide you want to try to extract the PDF layers, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352800/how-do-extract-text-layer-and-background-layer-from-pdf) to get a sense of what's involved.